How to exclude file which is rejected on push?
I am trying to push my repo to a remote and it complains about a file that is in a branch from far back. How can I remove the file from revision history, in order to push without being rejected for containing a large file?
I've tried using filter-repo with the path to the file, e.g.:
git filter-repo --path somewhere --invert-paths

I've tried deleting the branch and cloning single-branch, e.g.
git clone --no-local -b main --single-branch some some-other

I've tried using git gc
Still on push it complains about the file.

This seems to be a solution: Using https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ following the instructions.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history
